# PHP: Move associative array element to beginning of array

Tags: php

What would be the best method of moving any element of an associative array to the beginning of the array?

For example, say I have the following array:

```
$myArray = array(
    'two'   => 'Blah Blah Blah 2',
    'three' => 'Blah Blah Blah 3',
    'one'   => 'Blah Blah Blah 1',
    'four'  => 'Blah Blah Blah 4',
    'five'  => 'Blah Blah Blah 5',
);
```

What i want to do is move the 'one' element to the beginning and end up with the following array:

```
$myArray = array(
    'one'   => 'Blah Blah Blah 1',
    'two'   => 'Blah Blah Blah 2',
    'three' => 'Blah Blah Blah 3',
    'four'  => 'Blah Blah Blah 4',
    'five'  => 'Blah Blah Blah 5',
);
```

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can use the array union operator (`+`) to join the original array to a new associative array using the known key (`one`).

```
$myArray = array('one' => $myArray['one']) + $myArray;
// or      ['one' => $myArray['one']] + $myArray;
```

**Array keys are unique, so it would be impossible for it to exist in two locations.**

See further at the doc [on Array Operators:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

Comment: @andrewtweber No, I don't, but I did some testing and found that, compared to Emil's approach, it is 3x faster and takes half as much memory. I also found that it takes 20% more time than moving the same element to the end of the array.

Answer (score 7):

If you have numerical array keys and want to reindex array keys, it would be better to put it into `array_merge` like this:

```
$myArray = array_merge(array($key => $value) + $myArray );
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but in case anyone needs it, I created this little snippet.

```
function arr_push_pos($key, $value, $pos, $arr) 
{
    $new_arr = array();
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($arr as $arr_key => $arr_value) 
    {
        if($i == $pos) 
            $new_arr[$key] = $value;

        $new_arr[$arr_key] = $arr_value;

        ++$i;
    }

    return $new_arr;
}
```

Just adjust it to suit your needs, or use it and unset the index to move. Works with associative arrays too.

Comment: A correction:  $new_arr[$arr_key] = $arr_value; Should be:
if ($arr_key != $key)
   $new_arr[$arr_key] = $arr_value;
But otherwise: excellent! 1up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simple one-liner that gets this done using `array_splice()`:

```
$myArray = array_splice($myArray,array_search('one',array_keys($myArray)),1) + $myArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have 2 arrays,
1st has elements to move to the top of 2nd array of elements, you can use

```
$result = \array_replace($ArrayToMoveToTop, $myArray);
```

Here is a code sample:

```
//source array    
$myArray = [
    'two' => 'Blah Blah Blah 2',
    'three' => 'Blah Blah Blah 3',
    'one' => 'Blah Blah Blah 1',
    'four' => 'Blah Blah Blah 4',
    'five' => 'Blah Blah Blah 5',
];
// set necessary order
$orderArray = [
    'one' => '',
    'two' => '',
];
//apply it
$result = \array_replace($orderArray, $myArray);
\print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -2):

There's a function in the comments of the PHP manual for [array_unshift](http://php.net/array_unshift) which can be used to add an element, with key, to the beginning of an array:

```
function array_unshift_assoc(&$arr, $key, $val)
{
    $arr = array_reverse($arr, true);
    $arr[$key] = $val;
    return array_reverse($arr, true);
}
```

Unset the element and reinsert it again with the above function:

```
$tmp = $myArray['one'];
unset($myArray['one']);
$myArray = array_unshift_assoc($myArray, 'one', $tmp);
```

A more general approach may be to use [uksort](http://php.net/uksort) to sort your array by keys and provide a sorting function of your own.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer, though i dont want to sort the array in any way.  I want to be able to know an elements key and move only that specfic element to the beginning of the array

Comment: I think the "=" is a syntax error: `return = array_reverse($arr, true);`

Comment: Also, when I run your code I get an array with only one element in it... :-(